# How to access specific url after authentication with urllib2?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I was trying to build myself a very own app that shows me every day my school substitute plan (when teachers are ill/absent). The plan is always located on

```
https://ohmoor.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan/S-2018-10-30.htm
```

where `ohmoor.de` is the school server and `iserv` the portal. 
Eventually, I wanted to authenticate with `urllib` at the `https://ohmoor.de/iserv/login` with my username and password. As you can see when inspecting the website, the form sends a GET request to authenticate the input with the actual user. I then though I was logged in (after also getting the cookie) and tried to fetch the html code from 
`https://ohmoor.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan/S-2018-10-30.htm` which resulted in getting the html code from the log in form. Any ideas why it doesn't work and how to fix it?
This is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

my_url = "https://ohmoor.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan/S-2018-10- 
30.htm"


payload = {
    "username" : "<usernamehere>",
    "Password" : "<passwordhere>"
}

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

login_url = "https://ohmoor.de/iserv/login"

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url, data=payload)
    cookies = r.cookies
    r = s.get('https://ohmoor.de/iserv/plan/show/Vertretungsplan/S-2018-10- 
    30.htm', cookies=cookies)
    print(r.text)
```

The authentication seemed to work since I received a 200 status code when print r after the log in. Also you can only access the plan after authentication obviously.

Comment: The site may use javascript, so you'd need to use something like `selenium` for it to run.

Comment: *"resulted in getting the html code from the log in form"*: Then, you ar **not** logged in.

Comment: You could try using [Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) instead of your own `payload`